Getting conditions for existence of trigonometric solutions
Consider the following problem. Define a trigonometric function f(x):
f[x_]:=a*Sin[2*x]+b*Cos[2*x]+c*Cos[x]+d*Sin[x]-e

We want a range of $x$ for which $f(x)\leq 0$.
If I use Solve[f[x]==0,x], then Mathematica quickly returns a closed-form solution really fast. But it is an enormous solution. I don't need the exact solution. I need to know the conditions on $a$,$b$,$c$,$d$ and $e$, so that a solution exists. How do I proceed?

FullSimplify[Reduce[f[x]<=0,{a,b,c,d}]] gives conditions on a,b,c,d. Is that enough?

@Bill: That command produces an expression depending on x,a,b,c,d. A typical piece is (Cos[2 x] !=     0 && ((Cos[x] == 0 && ((d + b Cos[2 x] Csc[x] >= 0 && Sin[x] < 0). This is not it.

One thing you can do to simplify the result is to reduce the number of constants from 4 to 3.

@Bill, I dont think that is conditions on a,b,c,d. If I understood "user64494" correctly, then he is agreeing with me. When i use solve it gives me arctan of a huge combination of a,b,c,d. It returns multiple solutions and just using of of them isn't a good indicator of when a real solution exists. The curve goes below zero iff at least one real solution exists. The expression has a bunch of square roots. If I can get all the square roots that would also be helpful.

I wonder if taking the FourierTransform of both sides of f[x] == 0 could be helpful at all

@yarchik. Hi, first please note the modified problem which ends up adding one more variable. Secondly, no it doesnt help in simplifying (reducing the size of) the solution. Infact keeping it might be more instructive since one i get the condition, I might be able to identify symmetries that might make help reduce it. I know I'm being hopeful. But some of the squareroots in the expression seem to be similar, eg, the term
(b c + a d)^2/(4 (a^2 + b^2)^2) appears a lot. The term '-4 a^2 - 4 b^2 + c^2 + d^2 - 4 b e' appears a lot.

@Bill please check the modification. My problem is actually of the above form.

@ydd could you elaborate. The only thing i will get is a bunch of delta functions. How does that help in determining where the function is negative.

Theoretically, the reduction from trigonometry to algebra and usage of quantifiers should succeed, namely, Exists[{co,si},co^2+si^2==1,a*2*co*si+b*(co^2-si^2)+c*co+d*si-e<=0]:Resolve[%,Reals] . Unfortunately, my comp is not so strong to realize it.

I saw the output you had posted, i didn't get that. However, now when i try to run
Exists[{x, y}, x^2 + y^2 == 1,
a2 xy + b*(x^2 - y^2) + cx + dy - e <= 0]; Resolve[%, Reals]
I just get $aborted.

Try x*y instead of xy and c*x  instead of cx. Good lack!!!

the typos appear when i copy paste the code form mathematica.

But I think u have actually solved the problem. Or rather, given me a way to proceed. The idea is that we have two conics sections. I need to find conditions for when they intersect.

@ShohamSen I apologize. I think my suggestion of using FourierTransform is a dead end. I looked at applying other convolution integrals to the equation as well like LaplaceTransform but I don't think these add any additional traction to the problem. The closest I got was doing something similar to @user64494 ' s suggestion where I substituded TrigExpand[f[x] <= 0] /. {Sin[x] -> u, Cos[x] -> Sqrt[1 - u^2]} to get a rational instead of trig equation but it still seems like I've made no progress on solving the problem.

@ydd no worries thanks.

I am able to solve a simplified semi-algebraic problem on my comp. Reduction from trigonometry to polynomial algebra and usage of quantifiers succeed (Hope the notations are clear.).
Exists[{co, si}, co^2 + si^2 == 1, 
a*2*co*si + b*(co^2 - si^2) + d*si - e <= 0];Resolve[%,Reals]; LeafCount[%]


35057

The result in terms of Root is useless.

Couple of points-- (1) You forgot the c*co.
(2) The above thing just returns 1. (3) In the last result you had a typo c0 instead of co, this is why the results came out with c0^2<=1. I suspect that's why it worked/didnt work.

@ShohamSen: (1) I can solve only that  simplified problem. (2-3) Your claims are ungrounded and do not correspond to reality. That's all.

I see. Thanks for trying. Let me know if you end up solving it.
